# PHP - change index of parent in multi-dimensional array to child array value where key = string

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array, parent-child, usort

I've got an multi-dimensional array at the moment and want to remove the second-level of arrays and have the value of that second level as the new index value on the parent array. My current array is:

```
Array ( [0] => Array ( [connectee] => 1 ) [1] => Array ( [connectee] => 6 ) )
```

And want from that:

```
Array ( [0] => 1,  [1] =>  6 )
```

I was poking around the usort function but couldn't get it to work (where $current_connections is my array as above:

```
function cmp($a, $b) {
    return strcmp($a["connectee"], $b["connectee"]);
} 

$current_connections = usort($current_connections, "cmp");
```

The key doesn't need to be maintained (should be destroyed in the process).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
foreach ($array as &$value) {
    $value = $value['connectee'];
}
```

Comment: Works a charm. I thought it would be something simple! Thanks a ton.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** Please note that the question statement is very confusing and contradicting, but this answer is based upon your statement for expected output

> Array ( [0] => 1,  [1] =>  6 )

You could do

```
<?php
$values=array();
$values[0]=array("connectee"=>1);
$values[1]=array("connectee"=>6);
foreach($values as $index=>$value)
{
$values[$index]=$value["connectee"];
}
print_r($values);
?>
```